# OneNote link in Teams Tab is not working in Mobile

Tags: microsoft-teams, onenote, deeplink

The link navigates to a OneNote tab and is working fine in both browser Teams app and desktop Teams app, but it is not working in mobile Teams app.

The following shows the error in mobile.
[image]

I compared the links generated by OneNote in desktop and mobile Teams, they are different. I don't know why.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have just tested this in Teams mobile and the OneNote is working for me in my mobile.

**Steps to make it work:**

1. Make sure on your phone you are using your company mail exchange is configured in outlook. I have tested this in Android 8.
2. On your Android phone- It doesnt matter which account you are using to login to your OneNote books. But when you click the `onenote` link from your teams app it will ask you to sign in. Try signing in to your work account.
3. Then if you close the onenote app and open it again. You can easily see the onenote book which you have created from the Teams.

Try the above steps and please let me know. Hope it helps